# Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for where.: flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am tring to install and setup flutter by followig way
        1. I downloaded flutter and unzip
        2. Added path of flutter and bin folder in environment variable
        3. Fire command flutter doctor

Then dart has been downloaded via command line and then i got error

`Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for where.".                        Unable to generate crash report due to secondary error: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for where.
    please let us know at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.                                                        Unhandled exception:                                                                                                    ProcessExit: 1                                                                                                          #0      _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:149:7)                                                      #1      _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:87:64)                                #2      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)                                                                   #3      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)                                                            #4      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:155:20)                                                #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)                                   #6      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)                                               #7      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:534:5)                                                       #8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:15)                                    #9      _informUserOfCrash (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart)                                                          #10     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:87:64)                                #11     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)                                                                   #12     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)                                                            #13     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:155:20)                                                #14     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)                                   #15     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)                                               #16     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:534:5)                                                       #17     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:15)                                    #18     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart)                                                                 #19     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:87:64)                                #20     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)                                                                   #21     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)                                                            #22     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:155:20)                                                #23     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)                                   #24     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)                                               #25     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:534:5)                                                       #26     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:15)                                    #27     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart)                                                    #28     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:87:64)                                #29     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)                                                                   #30     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)                                                            #31     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:155:20)                                                #32     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)                                   #33     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)                                               #34     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:534:5)                                                       #35     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:15)                                    #36     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart)                                #37     _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:87:64)                                #38     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1204:38)                                                                   #39     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)                                                            #40     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:155:20)                                                #41     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:694:47)                                   #42     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:715:24)                                               #43     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:534:5)                                                       #44     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:582:7)                              #45     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)                                                                         #46     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)                                                                  #47     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)                                     #48     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)                                                       #49     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)                                                   #50     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)                                     #51     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:405:11)                                                   #52     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)                                                #53     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)`

Comment: Did you see [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15666) ?

Comment: yes I  have added  `C:\Windows\System32` in my path variable but not working.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by following 3 steps,

1. first step:- you need to disabled your virus guard,
2. second step:- you should remove cache folder entirely (it is located in ex:- 'C:\flutter\bin\cache')
3. Run 'Flutter Doctor'  which would download all artifacts again

Answer (score -3):

You have to install git and then restart your editors and your device