# Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument(s)

Tags: flutter

When I click Pub get in pubspec.yaml ana error pop up :

```sh
Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for C:\Users\Ali\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat.".
A crash report has been written to C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\inheritance_widgeta_context\flutter_17.log.
```

I have all the SDK tools updated

How to solve this issue?

this is the log:

Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

### command

`flutter --no-color pub get`

### exception

```sh
ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for C:\Users\Ali\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat.

#0      _getExecutable (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:125:5)
#1      LocalProcessManager.start (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:41:30)
#2      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.start.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:462:33)
#3      _run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:356:20)
#4      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.start (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:462:12)
#5      _DefaultProcessUtils.start (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:477:28)
#6      _DefaultProcessUtils.stream (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:496:35)
#7      _DefaultPub.batch (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:295:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      _DefaultPub.get (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:219:15)
#9      PackagesGetCommand._runPubGet (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:117:17)
#10     PackagesGetCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/packages.dart:151:11)
#11     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
#12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
#13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
#14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
#15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
#16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
#17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
#18     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
#19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
#20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
#21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
#22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
#23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

### flutter doctor

```sh
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\Users\Ali\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (4 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin installed
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61218939/invalid-arguments-cannot-find-executable-for-where-flutter

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by following 3 steps,

1-:- you need to disabled your virus guard,

2-:- you should remove cache folder entirely (it is located in ex:- 'C:\flutter\bin\cache')

3-: Run 'Flutter Doctor' which would download all artifacts again